# Rename Option - Amazon S3 or MS Azure or Google Cloud

Tags: azure

The customer will rename the folder often. In such a case, what would be the best cloud storage as Amazon S3 charges for each PUT request. Also, rename is not just renaming a folder in amazon in turn it does the copy and delete.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this kind of behavior almost with every cloud provider. To answer your concerns specifically:

> Amazon S3 charges for each PUT request.

Azure also charges for each PUT request and I am pretty sure Google does the same.

> Also, rename is not just renaming a folder in amazon in turn it does
>   the copy and delete.

Same is the deal with Azure as well. As of today, there's no inbuilt rename functionality. You would create a new blob by copying the source blob (with a new name of course) and then delete the source blob once the copy is successful.

Comment: i understand due to the architecture design it is expensive. Any design change expected or in pipeline to overcome this?

Comment: `Any design change expected or in pipeline to overcome this?` - I'm definitely not the right person to answer this as I am not part of the product team. What you need to do is go with what you have today. If things change in future, you simply change your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gaurav